# Find regular representation of $(\mathbb{Z}_3,+_3)$ in given base and reduce it

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory

So, first of all we have $\mathbb{Z}_3=\{0,1,2\}$ and base vectors $\{e_0,e_1,e_2\}=\{[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]\}$ numerated by elements of group, which means we are looking for representation $\phi:\mathbb{Z}_3\rightarrow GL(3,\mathbb{C})$. Regular representation is given by linear transformation $\phi_s$ (for element $s\in\mathbb{Z}_3$) such that for given vector from base $e_r$ it returns $\phi_s(e_r)=e_{rs}$, so for element $0$, it does nothing (doesn't change base vectors) so it's given by matrix

$0\mapsto \begin{bmatrix}1,0,0\\0,1,0\\0,0,1 \end{bmatrix}$, $1$ shifts everything by one so first vector in base is now second etc. so

$1\mapsto \begin{bmatrix}0,1,0\\0,0,1\\1,0,0 \end{bmatrix}$, and $2$ shifts everything by two, so

$2\mapsto \begin{bmatrix}0,0,1\\1,0,0\\0,1,0 \end{bmatrix}$.

Is my reasoning with regular representation for given base correct?

I suspect that it will reduce into three $\mathbb{C}$ representations, because i know that if group is abelian, then its irreducible representations are of dimension 1, but i don't know how to get them.

Answer (score 3):

You always have the trivial subrepresentation, given by the span of $e_1 + e_2 + e_3$.

Furthermore, to find them all, if an element is fixed by the generator of $\mathbb{Z}_3$, then it is fixed by $\mathbb{Z}_3$, so to find one dimensional $\mathbb{Z}_3$-invariant subspaces, this is equivalent to finding eigenvectors of the matrix of (what you have called) 1.

From this perspective, the trivial subrepresentation given above, corresponds to the eigenvector [1,1,1] with eigenvalue 1.

I hope this points you in the right direction!

Comment: could you tell me what do you mean with element being fixed by generator/group? I have found all three vectors (two are complex), why are subrepresentations related to eigenvectors? I guess by finding these vectors i can show that $\mathbb{C}^3$ is direct sum of span of them but how can i get subrepresentations from them? Is it even possible?

Comment: Is it because eigenvectors of such matrix are invariant for changing of base? And because 1 is generator of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ they are invariant for any of changes of bases given by regular representation?

Comment: @rubiccube713 I will write $\mathbb{Z}_3 = \{1 , x , x^2\}$ for clarity.
An element of $\mathbb{C}^3$ is fixed by $x$ if $xv = \lambda v$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. If this is true, then for any element $x^k \in \mathbb{Z}_3$, $x^k v = \lambda^k v$, so $v$ is fixed by the group (by all elements).

Comment: Notice that this condition is the same as $v$ being an eigenvalue of $x$. The thing to notice for cyclic groups is that an eigenvector $v$ of a group generator is an eigenvector for the whole group, and so the (1-dimensional) subspace spanned by $v$ is a $\mathbb{Z}_3$-subrepresentation.

Comment: @rubiccube713 does this clear things up?

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much :)